# copying table row and inserting using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CbRHu/  ..SO basically what I want to do here is when the last row's data selection ie the dropdownlist option value changes I want to create a new row and copy the value of the last row like all the td and inside stuff into this new row and append it to the table and then again when the last row which is the newly created row  changes another new row is created..Any idea how this can be done..

```
<table id="Main">
   <tr>
    <TD>
        <SELECT name=ctl00$m$g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf$ctl16>
          <OPTION value=1>WCF</OPTION>
          <OPTION value=2>ASP.Net</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=3>HTML</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=4>JS</OPTION> 
          <OPTION selected value=5>client</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
   </TD>
   <TD>
       <SELECT name=ctl00$m$g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf$ctl17> 
          <OPTION selected value=Begineer>Begineer</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Intermediate>Intermediate</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Expert>Expert</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Geek>Geek</OPTION>
       </SELECT>
    </TD>
  <TD style="COLOR: white">18</TD>   

<TR>
  <TD>
      <SELECT id=ctl00_m_g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf_TechCellDS onchange="Add()"       name=ctl00$m$g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf$TechCellDS>
        <OPTION value=1>WCF</OPTION> 
        <OPTION value=2>ASP.Net</OPTION> 
        <OPTION selected value=3>HTML</OPTION>
        <OPTION value=4>JS</OPTION>
        <OPTION value=5>client</OPTION> 
        <OPTION value=Select>Select</OPTION>
       </SELECT>
   </TD>
      <TD>
       <SELECT name=ctl00$m$g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf$ctl17 id=ctl00_m_g_c10b6cde_8531_45b1_aee8_b49b773919bf_TechCellDS onchange="Add()"> 
          <OPTION selected value=Begineer>Begineer</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Intermediate>Intermediate</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Expert>Expert</OPTION> 
          <OPTION value=Geek>Geek</OPTION>
       </SELECT>
    </TD>
    <tr>    
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using asp.net webforms clearly. Why not do it server side?

Comment: din't wanted a postback after every selection and this webpart lives in sharepoint 2007 and I am not sure if I can use AJAX so thought client side  would do the trick

Comment: in your generate HTML is not valid tr is not closed

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/9sQLb/

Comment: @A.V why you not posted it as answer  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the javascript:

```
var main = $('#Main');
var template = $('#Main').find("tr:first").html().toString();

function addTemplate() {
    main.find("tr:last").after('<tr>' + template + '</tr>');
}

$('.last:last').live('change', function () {
       addTemplate();
})
```

And a working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/CbRHu/12/

Comment: $(table).append($(table + ' tr:last').clone()); this seems to be working fine..I have only 2 issues remaining..So in the last row there are two dropdowns..I need to check that both of them have some value apart from select when this Add function is fired and if it passes then just call the above jquery which creates a new row..the second is that when this Add function is called after passing the test it should remove the onChange method from the last one and insert it into the newly created row..so maybe I am looking for how to get access to the values in the last row and modify or check them

Comment: ur example works perfectly the only thing is that it adds a new row when the last row changes..it will be nice if it checks for both the dropdown values to be changed..I have the default as just select and so it can be checked if the value is something else for both dropdowns and then insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
function addRow()
            {
                var n=$("#elementCount").val();
                var row=$('#rowid'+(n-1));
                row.clone(true).attr('id','rowid'+(n)).insertAfter(row);

                n++;

                $("#elementCount").val(n);
            }
```

elementCount=id of hidden field that contains num of rows.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden field

Comment: it is maintained so that $('#rowid'+(n-1)) will give me the last row object. I am considering tr id in row1, row2, row3 like this...

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for your question

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function addrow() {
        var newtr = $('#Main tr').eq(-1).html();
        $('#Main tbody').append('<tr>' + newtr + '</tr>');
    }
    $(document).on("change", $('#Main tr:last select'),

    function () {
        addrow();

    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/CbRHu/15/)

Comment: I have used on instead of live because live is deprecated .